# Code blocks have no background colour or scrollbars in beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, android-app

But graduated site posts seem to be normal.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Additionally, the scroll bar is too close to the text in single line code blocks. It looks weird.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: Nexus 5
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (2554798)

Comment: Can you confirm this has been fixed? Since there was never any 1.0.86 version, I'm not sure.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm on 1.0.89 now, and the code blocks have backgrounds

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So it was fixed only when 1.0.89 shipped?

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, I'm sure it was fixed earlier than that - my comment under Brian's answer came two weeks after the answer itself, and I usually don't accept answers on bug reports until I get a chance to test the fix, so I believe the fix was rolled out in about two weeks after the answer was posted

Comment: I see. Weird, so it was fixed in same version.

Comment: @ShadowWizard is it still happening for you?

Comment: No, I just try to sort things out with Brian on chat. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.86.

One of the cleanups I did for post rendering was to disable Prettify on sites that don't use it (like Vi and Vim).  Unfortunately, for whatever reason, some code for formatting code blocks and block quotes was tucked away in `prettify.css` so those sites are getting the built-in style rules for those elements.

Comment: Thanks for nuking the scrollbars altogether! They don't have much use on a touch screen.