# Color the background of block quotes on mobile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, markdown, mobile-web

The desktop site has a nice yellow background for block quotes.

As an example, [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277369/245360) shows block quotes like this on the desktop:

> [image: desktop]

But like this on mobile:

[image: mobile]

In my opinion, the background is helpful and makes the post easier to read / break down.

Can the background be added on the mobile web site too please?

Comment: Related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277913/270345

Comment: That is specifically to the android app, this is mobile web @muru

Comment: Yeap! I forgot to update this question. Actually, I've killed more mobile bugs and issues recently, so it's hard to track what exactly was fixed. Thanks for remainder!

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for fixing. It is a big delight to read it this way, very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been implemented as of today!

[image: Screen shot]